# Image positioning outside a div

Tags: css, html, positioning, image

i have set the top of an image to -200px relative to the div that contain that image. for example:

The problem is that the div "one" is hidding me the image that i put on "imageup". I tried setting up z-index on #imageup with no succeed. Heres is the specific problem:

http://www.ofertasybonos.com/ofertas-automovil

As you see the image coches.png is hidden by another div, how i solve this setting a css property on #imageup or on the coches.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `#imageup`:

- Change `position: relative` to `position: absolute`.
- Change `top: -200px` to `top: 100px`.
- [You win (demo)](http://jsbin.com/ududa).