# How can I specify distance between list items?

Tags: html, css

I want to set a distance of 20px between every single list.

HTML:

```
<div id="folio">
    <ul>
        <li><img src=""></li>
        <li><img src=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#folio { width:1200px; }
#folio ul li { width:588px; height:273px; display:inline-block; background:#cf5b6f; border:1px solid #8e1028; list-style:none; }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: css margin inside #folio ul li? have u tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Paul said, you should add:

```
#folio ul li{ margin:0 20px 20px 0; vertical-align:top}
```

Due to using `display: inline-block`, you should also remove the whitespace in your HTML, like this:

```
<div id="folio">
    <ul>
        <li><img src=""></li><li><img src=""></li><li><img src=""></li><li><img src=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I also added another `width` and then `overflow: hidden` to `#folio` to mask the extra `margin`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Brnsg/3/

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks :) [I do enjoy your special upvotes :D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235119/image-positioning-outside-a-div#comment-5899454)

Answer (score 4):

`folio ul li { margin: 0 20px 20px 0; }` should do the trick.  Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but with `display: inline-block;`, should you not also be adding `vertical-align: top;` to align the boxes?

Comment: well i am trying for vertical distance between list's as you can see i use inline-block